# Add TPT Inherited Code First Model to Linq Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, linq, inheritance, linq-to-entities

I'm having problems extending the Fluent API to my inheritance classes. I have taken the TPT (table per type) method and each type of the inheritance has a table. I like table per type because the database is fully normalized and easy to maintain. I am not getting the inherited model `ServiceCompany` to work with the Fluent API.

Base Abstract Class

```
public abstract class Vendor
{
    [Key]
    public int VendorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StreetNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
}
```

Inherited ServiceCompany Class from Vendor

```
[Table("ServiceCompanies")]
public class ServiceCompany : Vendor
{
    public string ACHClaim { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubContractorCompany> SubContractorCompanies { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceCompanyUser> SubContractorUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Where I added the entity models to enable the Fluent API with onModelCreating()

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceCompany>().ToTable("ServiceCompanies");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this with the fluent API.

```
var ListofServiceCompanies = db.ServiceCompanies.All()
```

and not like this

```
var ListofServiceCompanies = db.Vendor.SelectMany( Vendor is a ServiceComapny...etc)
```

I prefer to set up the entities correctly and make the code nice and easy to use. Any insight or knowledge is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by calling [**OfType**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method like below:

```
var ListofServiceCompanies = db.Vendor.OfType<Vendor>().ToList();
```

Or you can just add a `DbSet<ServiceCompany> ServiceCompanies { get; set; }` into your `DbContext` so it will look like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ServiceCompany> ServiceCompanies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceCompany>().ToTable("ServiceCompanies");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
var ListofServiceCompanies = db.ServiceCompanies.ToList();
```

Comment: Great explanation of setting up Fluent API for TPT (Table per Type) inheritance